# Summation Proof (Combinatorics)

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

The question says to prove that $$\sum_{n_1+n_2+n_3=n} \binom{n}{n_1,n_2,n_3}*(-1)^{n_1-n_2+n_3} = 1$$ where the summation extends over all nonnegative integral solutions of $$n_1+n_2+n_3=n.$$

I used the multinomial theorem to get:

$$(x_1+x_2+x_3)^n = \sum_{n_1+n_2+n_3=n} \binom{n}{n_1,n_2,n_3}*x_1^{n_1}*x_2^{n_2}*x_3^{n_3} $$

Then I substituted $$u=x_1=x_3$$ and $$u^{-1}=x_2:$$

$$(u+u^{-1}+u)^n = \sum_{n_1+n_2+n_3=n} \binom{n}{n_1,n_2,n_3}*u^{n_1-n_2+n_3} $$

But when I let $u=-1$, I don't get the summation equal to $1$. I think I must be doing something wrong on the left side of the equation?

Comment: Try substituting $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: Check with $n = 1$. You'll see that the equality doesn't hold.

Comment: As @Daniel says: things are wrong here. Also note that $(-1)^{-n_2}=(-1)^{n_2}$.

Comment: Should I have not substituted $$x_2=u^{-1}$$ then? I'm confused as to where I went wrong.

Comment: For $u = -1$, we have $u^{-1} = u$, so it doesn't matter whether one writes $x_2 = u^{-1}$ as you did, or first rewrites $(-1)^{n_1 - n_2 + n_3} = (-1)^{n_1 + n_2 + n_3}$ and then writes $x_2 = u$. In this case, it doesn't matter. (But if we had a factor $a^{n_1 - n_2 + n_3}$ in the sum with $a \neq \pm 1$, it would matter and your way of getting $(a + a^{-1} + a)^n$ would be the correct one.) The problem is not that you went wrong somewhere, it's that you were asked to prove a false assertion. $$\sum_{n_1+n_2+n_3=n}\binom{n}{n_1,n_2,n_3} (-1)^{n_1-n_2+n_3} = (-3)^n$$

Comment: @DanielFischer I thought that may be the case, but then the next question in the textbook is very similar and I thought that the odds that both were wrong were pretty slim. The other question is to prove that $$\sum_{n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4=n} \binom{n}{n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4}*(-1)^{n_1-n_2+n_3-n_4} = 0$$ Which has essentially the same problem that you wind up with it $$ = (-4)^n$$, not 0.

Comment: Right. We would have $$\sum_{n_1 + n_2 + n_3 = n} \binom{n}{n_1,n_2,n_3} 1^{n_1}\cdot (-1)^{n_2}\cdot 1^{n_3} = 1$$ and $$\sum_{n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4 = n} \binom{n}{n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4} 1^{n_1}\cdot (-1)^{n_2}\cdot 1^{n_3}\cdot (-1)^{n_4} = 0$$ for $n > 0$. In this case, I consider it unsurprising that the same mistake is made twice in a row, it would be more surprising if the mistake is made once and the neighbouring exercise avoids it.